# Send clear password via mail

Tags: users, email, user-registration, password

I need to send an email whenever a user is added or registers containing its clear password.
I know it's a bad idea in terms of security but I need to do it for a private project.
Any idea? Should I hook into user_register and do something or is there a simpler way?

I'm using Better Notification atm to manage my emails, thank you!

Answer (score 1):

user_register isn't the solution for your needs because when this action is trigger, the password is already encrypted.

The best solution is to do a custom registration form and insert your new users with this hook: [wp_insert_user()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_insert_user/)

When a user is register, you can send a custom email with the password not encrypted.